# I am getting a Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using this library (PHP Simple HTML DOM parser) to parse a link, here's the code:

```
        $html = getHTMLContentFromURL ( $url, $requestHeaders );
        foreach ( $html->find ( '#listStack' ) as $e ) {
            $stacks = split('split', $e);
            $values = array_shift($stacks);
            foreach ($stacks as $stack) {
                foreach ( $stack->find ( 'b' ) as $e1 ) {
                    $id = strip_tags ( $e1->innertext );
                }
                foreach ( $stack->find ( 'a' ) as $e2 ) {
                    $link = strip_tags ( $e2->href );
                    $title = strip_tags ( $e2->innertext );
                }
         }
```

but I am getting this error when I output the results:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\parser.php on line 108

```
Line 108 is the foreach ( $stack->find ( 'b' ) as $e1 )
```

Comment: put it inside a variable first and test it, most likely there's no `b` tag found

Comment: @Ghost b tag is there when I checked in the source file. It is mostly happening because of the split I'm doing, but I cannot process it without splitting. Is there an alternative for this??

Comment: $stack is supposed to an object but in some cases it is not apparently. You could guard against it with `instanceof` or `is_object` check on $stack.